# Jquery event onclick won't work

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I have a jquery click function like this :

```
$( "#kirimKririk" ).click(function() {
            alert("test klik");   
});
```

and this function provides event onclick on this html tag :

```
<input type="button" value="Kirim Komentar" id="kirimKritik"/>
```

Unfortunately that click function does not work at all..

I've checked the html tags on that page, moreover I use the application **[TagCheck HTML/XML](http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/tagcheck.html)** to check html tags, and no error messages.

Anyone can give suggestions what else should I check?

Comment: Typo in the selector or the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( "#kirimKritik" ).click(function() {
            alert("test klik");   
});
```

The id and selector didn't match.  You had a spelling error in the selector.

Comment: Damn, look's like my eyesight and concentration began to decline.. 
Thanks for the correction..
: )

Comment: @Rebel happens to everyone, I am notorious for using the class "." selector to style ids in my csss

Answer (score 3):

kirimKritik != kirimKririk so it'll never find it because they don't match.

Comment: Damn, look's like my eyesight and concentration began to decline.. 
Thanks for the correction.. 
: )

Answer (score 3):

The id is kirimKritik, but in your JS you're writing "#kirimKririk".

Answer (score 2):

spelt... please check it... it is `kirimKritik` not `kirimKririk`

Comment: My bad, the id and selectors that I wrote is different..

Thank you for correcting..

Problem SOLVED..